# Generate Monero Private/Public Key using PHP Only?

Tags: php

I'm trying to generate Private/Public Keys for Monero using only PHP.

This is the library I'm using:

https://github.com/sneurlax/monerophp/blob/master/src/cryptonote.php

This is my code:

```
require_once('src/cryptonote.php');

$Cryptonote = new Cryptonote();
$seed = $Cryptonote->gen_new_hex_seed(); //generate new random hex seed
$address = $Cryptonote->gen_private_keys($seed); //generate new random private key

print_r($address);
```

I receive this output:

**Notice: Undefined variable: spendkey in /var/www/html/monero/src/cryptonote.php on line 72
Array ( [spendKey] => c2c511418397a682834576441911a68fb7fc0ab55db4cbf5e11ecd647a6c7402 
[viewKey] => 4a078e76cd41a3d3b534b83dc6f2ea2de500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a400 )**

The $seed seems to output and change but the viewKey stays the same.

How would I code this properly so that I can implement this in a webstore without using the Monero daemon?

Also, is there any downsides to generating keys like this?

Comment: The viewkey should change along with the spend key I believe researching Monero. Are these keys actually valid?

Comment: The issue seems to be what @jtgrassie addressed. Simply change the lowercase K to uppercase and you should be set. I was able to generate these keys using your code: Array ( [spendKey] => acd05059cfb02793ac9e29598c345fffbd397d8691ee9408f7654b6cb9b1ab0c [viewKey] => 2bdeaed3876b9c7e76ce009bafb97b7967e88a45797d1a05a65bf3bdd1ac250b ) Array ( [spendKey] => e0733665e3daf59ebf3dad20f923d4b9d57c2cadd6a2c05d120e602fa1e9fd05 [viewKey] => 6ff2b6d65fe211733fffde88ccf26ba5c695c4049c7ff0fdad63331b2569f409 ) Array ( [spendKey] => a2c314fb21571f6486c2a176b0cbce6cd8968c409866e2f5f6d68c986a23f001 [viewKey] =>

Answer (score 1):

Line [72](https://github.com/sneurlax/monerophp/blob/49ad5867a8dea0ee1c1542a6d5d53c50dfc6c7b3/src/cryptonote.php#L72) in that file has a variable name that doesn't match the parameter name (notice the lowercase k in spendkey). Just edit that line replacing `$spendkey` with `$spendKey` should fix it.